# Mixed Integer Linear Programming: how to find second greatest value in array

Tags: linear-programming

I am trying to determine the logic necessary to find the second greatest value in an array of values **in a MILP**.

Finding the maximum value is easy:

    `forall(val in Array):
        maxVal >= val`

However the second greatest value is much more difficult (if impossible?).
I have tried the following:

    `forall(val in Array | val != maxVal):
        secondMaxVal >= val`

This logic fails in the MILP (I am programming in Mosel - the FICO Xpress language), perhaps because my `Array` actually has two dimensions and **contains decision variables**. Because of the two dimensions, the logic in my program looks more like:

    `forall(i in Index1):
        maxVal >= sum(j in Index2) Array(i, j)
    forall(i in Index1 | sum(j in Index2) Array(i, j) != maxVal):
        secondMaxVal >= sum(j in Index2) Array(i, j)`

Note that `|` is interpreted as "where". The program balks at the `!=` statement, calling it `invalid logic` - probably because `Array` contains decision variables, i.e. the values are determined by the objective function, which effectively minimizes the values in `Array`, where all values in `Array` are > 0.

**Is it possible to define the second greatest value in an array of decision variables in a MILP?**

Comment: (1) Your first approach seems to be depending on the remaining problem to me (e.g. objective is pushing maxVal towards -inf). (2) MILP can formulate anything (i won't get into too much details in regards to theory here). (3) The question is: is there a MILP-free approach and i think there is; maybe even using LP only (but maybe something more powerful as SOCP). (4) In MILP you can always do the following: pairwise (quadratic)  binary-comparison >= together with indicator-variables; then chosing the one where exactly (N-1) indicators are true (ignoring corner-cases here).

Comment: Thanks @sascha. I don't understand all of your comments, but perhaps I should note that the values in `Array` are constrained to be greater than zero.